# Javascript inside Kendo Template is giving incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a template with javascript inside it

```
    # if(IsSelected) { #
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
    </tr>
    # } #
```

It is intended to show only those records for which the IsSelected value is true. Though it shows only two records – the records displayed are not correct. What is the reason for this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/4/

**CODE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template Filtering</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
      <script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        # if(IsSelected) { #
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
        </tr>
        # } #
    </script>
    <!--MVVM Wiring using Kendo Binding-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);
        });

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({

            employees: [
                        { name: "Lijo", age: "28", IsSelected: true },
                        { name: "Binu", age: "33", IsSelected: false },
                        { name: "Kiran", age: "29", IsSelected: true }
                       ]
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        table, th, td
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: employees">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Working Example:- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/15/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try defining the template as:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if(IsSelected) { #
    <tr>
        <td>#= name #</td>
        <td>#= age #</td>
    </tr>
    # } #
</script>
```

in order to avoid a *double* bind first in the `tbody` and then in the `td`.

**EDIT**: In order to avoid the problems with the error that throws KendoUI, I would change your code a little and instead of using a `kendo.observable` I would use a `DataSource` that implements `filter`s.

So, you don't need to print or not the row in your template but setting the filter condition in the `DataSource`.

Define the template as follow:

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr>
        <td>#= name #</td>
        <td>#= age #</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

and your JavaScript code as:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data  : {
        employees: [
            { name: "Lijo", age: "28", IsSelected: true },
            { name: "Binu", age: "33", IsSelected: false },
            { name: "Kiran", age: "29", IsSelected: true }
        ]
    },
    schema: {
        data: "employees"
    },
    filter: { field: "IsSelected", operator: "eq", value: true }
});
```

Where I set a `filter` that filters out elements where `isSelected` is not equal to `true`.

Then initialize a ListView as follow:

```
$("#list").kendoListView({
    dataSource: ds,
    template  : $("#row-template").html()
});
```

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Z86dq/16/

Comment: Thanks - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/Z86dq/15/). Though there is double bind first in the tbody and then in the td, why is Kendo showing incorrect result, rather than an error? Is there any documentation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is my syntax, but this is coming from a sub grid. So I think the syntax you need may be a little different. I think //# just becomes # if it's in the parent Grid but don't quote me on it. Looks like your missing some " " and concatenation

Here's the razor syntax for what it's worth, maybe you can convert it to your needs

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(x => x.FirstName).Title("First Name").ClientTemplate(
    "# if (Id == 5) { #" +
        ("<a class href='javascript: void(0);' onclick=\"return MyFunction('#=LastName#', '#= FirstName #');\">Convert</a>") +
        "# } else { #" +
                        "#= FirstName #" +
                    "# } #");
    columns.Bound(x => x.LastName).Title("Last Name");
    columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Title("User ID");    

})
```

So this code reads as, If the Id of the user is 5, the column will have a hyperlink that says "convert" and will call MyFunction with those parameters. If not show the user's name

Comment: I am NOT using `ASP.Net MVC`. It is complete client side code

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the fact that the MVVM implementation expects the template to render one element. In your case, you can use the visible binding - check an [updated version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KjF9/).

```
    <tr data-bind="visible: IsSelected">
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
    </tr>
```